# Event handling method not working correctly

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, event-handling

I am creating a GUI application using JavaFX in Eclipse. In this application I am creating a map of squares where you can toggle the square between filled space and empty space. I want the program to allow the user to toggle all the squares except for those on the edges but for some reason my handle method is allowing me to toggle all the squares. I just want to know if my handler method is fine or not.Thanks in advance for help.

this is how the GUI should look like
[image]

This is my GUI class called mazeGuiPane
    package lab8;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MazeGuiPane extends Application {
    private GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    private BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
    private Scene sc = new Scene(border);
    public Label[][] labelGridArray = new Label[20][20];
    private StreetMap map = new StreetMap();
    int col;
    int row;

    public void start(Stage primary) {

        sc.getStylesheets().add("/styles/style.css");
        grid.getStyleClass().add("grid-style");
        border.getStyleClass().add("border-style");
        Label mainTitle = new Label("Map Of Pamplona");
        mainTitle.getStyleClass().add("white-text");
        Button butt = new Button("RUN!");
        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        HBox buttHBox = new HBox();
        HBox titleBox = new HBox();
        VBox titleVBox = new VBox();
        VBox buttVBox = new VBox();

        map.makeGrid();

        for (col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
                Label square = new Label();
                if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == ' ') {
                    square.getStyleClass().add("default-box");
                } else if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == 'S') {
                    square.setText("Start");
                    square.getStyleClass().add("start-end");
                } else if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == 'E') {
                    square.setText("End");
                    square.getStyleClass().add("start-end");
                } else {
                    square.getStyleClass().add("wall");
                }

                square.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                        row = GridPane.getRowIndex(square);
                        col = GridPane.getColumnIndex(square);
                        for (int col = 1; col < 19; col++) {
                            for (int row = 1; row < 19; row++) {
                                if (map.gridArray[col][row].getTier() != 0
                                    || map.gridArray[col][row].getTier() != 19
                                    || map.gridArray[col][row].getColumn() != 0
                                    || map.gridArray[col][row].getColumn() != 19) {
                                    if(map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == 'W'){
                                        square.getStyleClass().removeAll("wall");
                                        square.getStyleClass().add("default-box");
                                        map.gridArray[col][row].setTier(row); 
                                        map.gridArray[col][row].setColumn(col); map.gridArray[col][row].setValue(' ');
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        square.getStyleClass().removeAll("default-box");
                                        square.getStyleClass().add("wall");
                                        map.gridArray[col][row].setTier(row); 
                                        map.gridArray[col][row].setColumn(col);
                                        map.gridArray[col][row].setValue('W');

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                labelGridArray[col][row] = square;
                grid.add(square, col, row);
            }
        }
        titleBox.getStyleClass().add("title");
        titleBox.getChildren().add(mainTitle);
        titleVBox.getChildren().add(titleBox);

        buttHBox.getStyleClass().add("button-style");
        buttHBox.getChildren().add(butt);
        buttVBox.getChildren().add(buttHBox);

        vBox.getChildren().add(grid);

        border.setTop((titleBox));
        border.setCenter(vBox);
        border.setBottom(buttVBox);

        primary.setScene(sc);
        primary.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post [mcve] so we don't have to do guesswork. If you want to toggle only the clicked square there is no need to iterate all of them (or most of them)

Comment: *I just want to know if my handler method is fine or not.*: if it doesn't do what you want it to do, how could it be fine? Why do you add an event handler to those squares in the first place if they aren't supposed to be clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a label is clicked you update this lable for every label except for border labels. This is probably not what you want.

Furthermore the value you write to the `column` and `row` fields doesn't seem to be used anywhere. You should remove them and stick to local variables.

If you don't want to trigger updated when a label on the border is clicked you could simply not register listeners for those nodes. Move the label creation and the handler registration to different loops:

```
for (int col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
        Label square = new Label();
        if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == ' ') {
            square.getStyleClass().add("default-box");
        } else if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == 'S') {
            square.setText("Start");
            square.getStyleClass().add("start-end");
        } else if (map.gridArray[col][row].getValue() == 'E') {
            square.setText("End");
            square.getStyleClass().add("start-end");
        } else {
            square.getStyleClass().add("wall");
        }
        labelGridArray[col][row] = square;
        grid.add(square, col, row);
    }
}
for (int col = 1; col < 19; col++) {
    final int finalCol = col; // copy accessible from handler
    for (int row = 1; row < 19; row++) {
        final int finalRow = row; // copy accessible from handler
        final Label square = labelGridArray[col][row];
        square.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
               if (map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].getValue() == 'W'){
                    square.getStyleClass().remove("wall");
                    square.getStyleClass().add("default-box");
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setTier(finalRow); 
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setColumn(finalCol);
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setValue(' ');
                } else {
                    square.getStyleClass().remove("default-box");
                    square.getStyleClass().add("wall");
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setTier(finalRow); 
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setColumn(finalCol);
                    map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setValue('W');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Additional notes:**

- Unless `getColumn` and `getTier` returns different values the following disjunction always yields `true`, since a primitive value cannot be equal to both `0` and `19`.

  ```
  if (map.gridArray[col][row].getTier() != 0
      || map.gridArray[col][row].getTier() != 19
      || map.gridArray[col][row].getColumn() != 0
      || map.gridArray[col][row].getColumn() != 19) {
  ```
- Better use an enum instead of `char` for the value. This allows you to add data/methods to the object and also prevents you from accidentally using wrong values or the wrong case.

  ```
  public enum CellType {
      EMPTY("", "default-box"),
      START("Start", "start-end"),
      END("End", "start-end"),
      WALL("", "wall");

      private final String styleClass;
      private final String text;

      CellType(String text, String styleClass) {
          this.text = text;
          this.styleClass = styleClass;
      }

      public String getStyleClass() {
          return styleClass;
      }

      public String getText() {
          return text;
      }

      public Values inverted() {
          // this requires the values to be kept in this order
          CellType[] vals = values();
          return vals[vals.length - 1 - ordinal()];
      }
  }
  ```

  This allows you to simplify the code in the handler:

  ```
  CellType type = map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].getValue();
  square.getStyleClass().remove(type.getStyleClass());
  type = type.inverted();
  map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setValue(type);
  square.getStyleClass().add(type.getStyleClass());

  // are the following lines really necessary?
  map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setTier(finalRow);
  map.gridArray[finalCol][finalRow].setColumn(finalCol);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the question could look like. The following code also demonstrates a simplified implementation responding to a mouse click as you need :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MazeGuiPane extends Application {

    private int gridSize = 20;
    int col, row;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) {

        StreetMap map = new StreetMap();
        map.makeGrid(gridSize);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        for (col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
                grid.add(map.getGridArray()[row][col], col, row);
            }
        }
        primary.setScene(new Scene(grid));
        primary.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

//represents a single square
class Square extends Label{
    private int squareSize = 20;
    private static final String empty = " ",  wall = "W"; //better use enum

    Square(){   this(empty); }

    Square(String txt){
        setText(txt);
        setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        setPrefSize(squareSize,squareSize);
    }

    void toggle() {
        setText( getText().equals(empty) ?  wall : empty);
    }
}

//represents grid of squares
class StreetMap {

    private Label[][] gridArray;

    public void makeGrid(int size) {
        gridArray = new Square[size][size];
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                Label square = new Square();
                gridArray[row][col] = square;
                //add handler to those who need to respond to mouse clicks
                if((row > 0) && (row < (size -1)) ) {
                    if((col > 0) && (col < (size -1)) ) {
                        square.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                                ((Square)square).toggle();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Label[][] getGridArray() { return gridArray; }
}
```

**EDIT**
An improved version, following kleopatra's comments :

```
public class MazeGuiPane extends Application {

    private int gridSize = 20;
    int col, row;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary) {

        StreetMap map = new StreetMap();
        map.makeGrid(gridSize);
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        for (col = 0; col < 20; col++) {
            for (row = 0; row < 20; row++) {
                grid.add(map.getGridArray()[row][col].getNode(), col, row);
            }
        }

        primary.setScene(new Scene(grid));
        primary.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

//represents a single square
class Square{
    private Label label;
    private int squareSize = 20;
    private static final String empty = " ",  wall = "W"; //better use enum
    private SimpleStringProperty squareText = new SimpleStringProperty();

    Square(){ this(empty); }

    Square(String txt){
        squareText.set(txt);
        label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(squareText);
        label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        label.setPrefSize(squareSize,squareSize);
    }

    void toggle() {
        squareText.set(squareText.get().equals(empty) ?  wall : empty);
    }

    void addMouseHandler() {
        label.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) { toggle();}
        });
    }

    Node getNode() {return label; }
}

//represents grid of squares
class StreetMap {

    private Square[][] gridArray;

    public void makeGrid(int size) {
        gridArray = new Square[size][size];
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
            for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
                Square square = new Square();
                gridArray[row][col] = square;
                //add handler to those who need to respond to mouse clicks
                if((row > 0) && (row < (size -1)) ) {
                    if((col > 0) && (col < (size -1)) ) {
                        square.addMouseHandler();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Square[][] getGridArray() { return gridArray; }
}
```

Comment: sigh .. don't extend controls (or any other class) if you can reach the same goal by configuration - yeah I know it's just an example :)

Comment: Indeed (0:. It makes the example simpler to follow I think. I assume you mean get the Label by composition rather than inheritance ?

Comment: ideally, you would have a (mini-)model that has a property on/off: this is changed by whatever mechanism. Then bind the label's text to that property and .. be happy :)

Comment: hmm ... not exactly what I meant: never mix view and model <g> Keep the label out of it, create and configure it inside the grid building loop.